# Global variable loses its value after a local function finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little piece of code

---

**JS**

```
function insertDataIntoTable(jsonUrl, Id) {
    var obj;
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data){
        console.log("1: "+data.elem[Id]);  //outputs the correct object
        obj= data.elem[Id];
        console.log("2: "+obj);            //still is correct
    });
    console.log("3: "+obj);                //now it logs "undefined"
}
```

---

which refers to a well-formed JSON which don't wanna post if not really necessary. I hope someone can help me anyway.

Comment: it's all about the asynchrony - try putting `async ` before `function insertDataIntoTable` and `await` before `$.getJSON` - though you don't need to .. you know where the data is available, inside the callback - so do what you need there

Comment: Want to add here is that if you add a number to console log it will be clear that the second one is called before the one inside the getJSON callback.
So yes, why do you need it to be available after the getJSON out of the callback? Try to set the correct target and we'll be able to help.

Comment: function insertDataIntoTable(jsonUrl, Id) {
    let obj;
    let promice = new Promise((resolve) => {
        $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data) {
            console.log("1: " + data.elem[Id]); //outputs the correct object
            obj = data.elem[Id];
            console.log("2: " + obj);
            resolve(obj)
            //still is correct
        });
    })
    promice.then((obj) => {
        console.log("3: " + obj); //now it logs "undefined"
    })
}

Answer (score 2):

```
function insertDataIntoTable(jsonUrl, Id) {
var obj;
var callback = function(){
    console.log("3: "+obj);                //now it logs "undefined"
}
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data){
    console.log("1: "+data.elem[Id]);  //outputs the correct object
    obj= data.elem[Id];
    console.log("2: "+obj);            //still is correct
    callback();
});
}
```

Comment: it will `undefined ` as when your **callback** function was defined value of `obj` was `undefined` because **callback** function is  a **closure**

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous by nature. So when `insertDataIntoTable` method is called it will execute in following step.

1. define `var obj;`
2. do the ajax call to your `jsonUrl` using `$.getJSON`
3. `console.log("3: "+obj);`  Here your `obj` will be `undefined`
   as its not defined any value yet
4. execute the success/failure callback of your ajax call (using `$.getJSON` )where your getting  `console.log("1: "+data.elem[Id]);` and `console.log("2: "+obj);` absolutely right

There is nothing wrong in your code.

If you want to make above code **synchronous** then you can do by following methods:

1) use **`$.ajax`** using **`async:false`**

```
function insertDataIntoTable(jsonUrl, Id) {
    var obj;
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: jsonUrl,
      data: data,
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        obj = data.elem[Id]
      }
    });
    console.log(obj);
  }
```

2). If your using **`es6`** or **higher** the use **`async`** & **`await`**

```
let insertDataIntoTable = async (jsonUrl, Id) => {
    let obj;
    let data = await $.getJSON(jsonUrl);
    obj = data.elem[Id];
  }
```